# Can you please check "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can You please check this code once, why 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'' this error comes in python.

Code :

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  check = len(str -1)
  if check < n or n < 0:
      return False
  else:
      front = str[:n]
      back = str[n+1:]
      return front + back
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the `)` in the wrong place, `- 1` should be outside of it:

```
def missing_char(str, n):
  check = len(str) - 1
  if check < n or n < 0:
      return False
  else:
      front = str[:n]
      back = str[n+1:]
      return front + back
```

Comment: Is there a Python linter that checks for this mistake? Using that linter could help avoid this mistake and many similar ones in the future. Mentioning such a linter would make this answer useful.

Comment: @RolandIllig I don't know any, Spyder isn't... idle isn't... pycharm isn't, right?